# Preserving "this" when calling a function from another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I am trying to solve this problem.

Sample code from Secrets of the Javascript Ninja:

```
Function.prototype.memoized = function(key){
    this._values = this._values || {};
    return this._values[key] !== undefined ?
        this._values[key] :
    this._values[key] = this.apply(this, arguments);
};
function isPrime( num ) {
  var prime = num != 1;

  for ( var i = 2; i < num; i++ ) {
    if ( num % i == 0 ) {
      prime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return prime;
}
alert(isPrime.memoized(5);
```

This code gives us a convenient way of adding functionality, by adding a function to the Function prototype.

However, the "this" reference gets messed up, if I convert this function to use an object in Javascript:

JSFiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/vcqqc8a8/3/

```
function Test() {
    this.testVar = 2;
};

Test.prototype.isPrime = function (num) {
   alert(this.testVar); // This works, when isPrime is called through obj.isPrime(), but not when its called through memoized()
   var prime = num != 1;

   for ( var i = 2; i < num; i++ ) {
     if ( num % i == 0 ) {
       prime = false;
       break;
     }
   }
   return prime;
};

var t = new Test();
t.isPrime(5);                           // "this" inside Test.prototype.isPrime is correctly set to "t"
t.isPrime.memoized(5);      // "this" inside Test.prototype is set to isPrime (expected behavior, but I want it to be preserved to "t').
```

The problem is that "this" is changed to the caller, so in the case of the second call (t.isPrime.memoized(5)), "this" is set to isPrime, which causes memoized to correctly call isPrime. However, when isPrime is actually called, I want "this" to correctly become "t".

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: The only way I see to support this usage is to give every `Test` object its own `isPrime` function in the constructor.

Comment: *However, when isPrime is actually called, I want "this" to correctly become "t".* that's wrong. `this` references to your `t` inside your `isPrime` method

Comment: @TheReason What are you talking about? At the call to `isPrime`, `this` is `isPrime`.

Comment: @melpomene i'm talking about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uk3cjcv0/) case

Comment: @TheReason Yes, that's the case that's working as expected. OP is asking how to make `t.isPrime.memoized(5)` work.

Comment: @melpomene: About your original idea, can you please provide a sample JSFiddle. I am confused about what you mean by, give each object it's own isPrime function in the constructor?

Comment: @TahaAhmad instead of assigning `isPrime` to ptototype object add it to `this.isPrime` in *Test* constructor

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vcqqc8a8/4/

Comment: @TheReason Thank you for that... perhaps you can make an answer out of that and I can upvote

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
t.isPrime = t.isPrime.bind(t);
t.isPrime.memoized(5);
```

or you fix `memoized` to pass the appropriate `this`. And not to store its cache values on the function, which won't really work for a prototype where the method is shared but usually each instance needs its own cache.